# SVM sklearn verbose shows only dots

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

I use sklearn SVM with poly kernel and want to show progress or estimate the remaining time. I found verbose option, but this only results into lots of dots in terminal. Is this normal? And is there possibility to show progress or estimate remaining time?

```
svr_poly = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', verbose=True)
```

Comment: It should show the progress, like `*.*
optimization finished, #iter = 400
obj = -0.000000, rho = 0.740273
nSV = 161, nBSV = 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to show estimation of the remaining time, as during numerical optimization it is impossible to get such information. Verbosity of libsvm (used by sklearn) only shows you progress in terms of iterations (each dot) and finally - with the optimization results.